# On using capital/small letter in a question after a double colon

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, questions, capitalization

I have a sentence with a double colon, then a question. When I use double colons, I used to use small letters after it. But it is not clear what is the case if the sentence after the double colons is a question.

So the sentence look similar to:

> We set to answer the following question: Is method X faster than
>   method Y?

vs.

> We set to answer the following question: is method X faster than
>   method Y?

Comment: I would consider that particular question a "full sentence" and then follow the published [guidance](https://klwightman.com/2018/01/08/when-do-you-capitalize-after-a-colon/) accordingly.

Comment: This is a question of *style* not *grammar*, and is up to your own personal preference -- unless you are following a particular style guide.

Comment: The *Chicago Manual of Style* says to use an uppercase letter after a colon if what follows the colon is a question—which this is. But that only applies if you follow *Chicago*. Also, it's just *a colon*, not *a **double** colon*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a capital letter here. [Generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)#Use_of_capitals) American usage has a capital for any independent clause following a colon. British usage tends to use a capital less often, but when the colon introduces a direct quote or a direct question, most style guides would approve of a capital letter.